# Wanting to Change specific Characters from TextFile into Other Characters. Not trying to Write, only wanting to print out into the console

Tags: file, python-3.x, character

I have a text file that has a bunch of data in it. At certain instances of this text file, I am trying to replace the follow letters in it: A->G, C->T, etc. Basically, I know I need to read the file. Search through the lines of the file. Find the occurrences of these characters and then replace. Basically --> ACTG should be come GTCA.

My code so far is as follows:

```
f = open("actg.txt", "r")

table = str.maketrans("actgACTG", "gtcagtca")

print(f.read().translate(str.maketrans('ACTGactg','gtcagtca')))


print(table)
```

This output here is working properly. However, it's changing ALL instances of such letters in the entire file.

What if I only want the characters to change like this when they're in this particular sequence? Otherwise, as it is, it changes every 'a' and every 'g' in the entire file. I would like to keep normal sentences intact and only have this change made when this particular sort of sequence is present.

Comment: you shouldn't edit your original question and change it completely. It makes the answers seem irrelevant or unrelated. Add to it instead so others can understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.translate` in combination with `string.maketrans` (Python 2.x) or `str.maketrans` (Python 3.x):

Python 2.x:

```
>>> import string
>>> instring = 'ABCD'
>>> instring.translate(string.maketrans('ACac','gtgt'))
'gBtD'
```

Python 3.x:

```
>>> instring = 'ABCD'
>>> instring.translate(str.maketrans('ACac','gtgt'))
'gBtD'
```

`translate` requires a 256 character mapping table. This is what `string.maketrans` creates, mapping each character to itself, except for characters in the first argument string which are mapped to the corresponding character in the second argument string.

Comment: I may be doing it wrong, but I am getting this error then:

    instring.translate(string.maketrans('AC','GT'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans

Comment: It's version 3.2. And I'm using PyDev 2.7 with Eclipse

Comment: Hm, right but then how is getting the maketrans parameter actually converting the characters for me?

Comment: I think I understand, but I feel is all this necessary for my project?? I think this may be more advanced than what I am able to do at the current time. I think a better solution may be one that encompasses if/then/for loops. Loops through the file, gets the characters one by one and just switches them over. Sorry, I am just a beginner, really.

Comment: No, I agree with you. I realize it's a strong feature of python so I should try to make use of it. I keep trying to play around with it, but am not getting the output I desire. First, I used the 'makestran' then used 'translate' after, yet I am still getting the output as numbers. I thought maketrans creates the array for me and then translate replaces characters

Comment: Actually, I think I got it, does this seem correct:

            f = open("actg.txt", "r")

         table = str.maketrans("acgtACGT", "gtcagtca")

      print(f.read().translate(str.maketrans('ACGTacgt','gtcagtca')))


       print(table)

Comment: It's returning the correct output now. However, one question: what if there's other text in the file such as: "Grapes are good." I don't want the text in that sentence to start changing (ie it would be Argpes gre aood" because of the switches from a to g. What if I only wanted it to make these changes when such consecutive sequences are present so it doesn't modify every single character in the file and keeps normal sentences still intact?

Comment: That is no longer related to your original question. Something like this would work, however: f.read().replace('acgt','gtca').replace('ACGT','GTCA').

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> table = maketrans("acgtACGT", "gtcagtca")
```

Python 3:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans("acgtACGT", "gtcagtca")
```

Both:

```
>>> "acGTagTTcGTAC".translate(table)
'gtcagcaatcagt'
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named maketrans

Not sure why that's happening. It's Python 3.2

Comment: Ah, you're on Python 3, I see.

Comment: f = open("actg.txt", "r")
table = str.maketrans("acgtACGT", "gtcagtca")
print(table)


That's giving me the following output: {97: 103, 67: 116, 65: 103, 103: 99, 99: 116, 116: 97, 84: 97, 71: 99}

Comment: yes, that's right: `maketrans` creates a translation table. It should be the parameter to the `translate` method of strings.

Comment: Hm, right but then how is getting the maketrans parameter actually converting the characters for me? I figured when I'd do a print(table) it will spit back out the conversions I wanted.

Comment: Try `for line in f: print(line.translate(table))`.

Comment: t's returning the correct output now. However, one question: what if there's other text in the file such as: "Grapes are good." I don't want the text in that sentence to start changing (ie it would be Argpes gre aood" because of the switches from a to g. What if I only wanted it to make these changes when such consecutive sequences are present so it doesn't modify every single character in the file and keeps normal sentences still intact?

Comment: `f = open("actg.txt", "r")   
    table = str.maketrans("actgACTG", "gtcagtca")     
   print(f.read().translate(str.maketrans('ACTGactg','gtcagtca')))   
    print(table)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change upper and lower case at the same time using the re lib:

```
In [3]: re.sub('[Aa]', 'g', 'HAllat')
Out[3]: 'Hgllgt'
```

Here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sub'

It's python 3.2. Not sure why that's happening

Comment: @user1985793 I've tried with 3.2 and I get the same result. Can you try again, copy-pasting the line as here: re.sub('[Aa]', 'g', 'HAllat')